# SQL select dependent on count with condition

Tags: sql, select, count, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
Table A:                Table B:
id  name               id   a_id   param
1    xxx               1      1      3
2    yyy               2      1      4
                       3      1      5
                       4      2      3
                       5      2      4
                       6      2      9
```

I need to select from Table A such names where a number of related rows from B with `3 <= param <= 5` is less than 3.

In the case above it should yield only `yyy`, because it has only 2 related rows from B which
have `3 <= param <= 5`. While `xxx` has 3 related rows with such condition.

Comment: Looks like a GROUP BY and HAVING question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following using a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT A.name 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id AND B.param BETWEEN 3 AND 5 
GROUP BY A.name 
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
```

---

In case you need all columns of table `A` you can use the following using a `INNER JOIN` with the above `SELECT`:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A.id 
    FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id AND B.param BETWEEN 3 AND 5 
    GROUP BY A.id 
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
) A2 ON A.id = A2.id;
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jBCw5G1LvrRC37TLVx3UsB/1

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can use `group by` and `join`:

```
select a.*
from a left join
     (select a_id, count(*) as cnt
      from b
      where param >= 3 and param <= 5
      group by a_id
     ) b
     on b.a_id = a.id
where b.cnt < 3 or b.cnt is null;
```